# How do I group records having time difference of more than an hour?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm new to this site but bear with me.

I'm trying to `GROUP BY` some data using SQL Server.

Here's the data:

```
Computer    VisitDate
ComputerA   2012-04-28 09:00:00
ComputerA   2012-04-28 09:05:00
ComputerA   2012-04-28 09:10:00
ComputerB   2012-04-28 09:30:00
ComputerB   2012-04-28 09:32:00
ComputerB   2012-04-28 09:44:00
ComputerB   2012-04-28 09:56:00
ComputerB   2012-04-28 10:25:00
ComputerA   2012-04-28 12:25:00
ComputerC   2012-04-28 12:30:00
ComputerC   2012-04-28 12:35:00
ComputerC   2012-04-28 12:45:00
ComputerC   2012-04-28 12:55:00
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to group the data by Computer but also group if a Computer has a difference between a visit time longer than 1 hour. Here is the result of what I'm trying to do:

```
Computer     VisitDate
ComputerA    2012-04-28 09:00:00
ComputerB    2012-04-28 09:30:00
ComputerA    2012-04-28 12:25:00
ComputerC    2012-04-28 12:30:00
```

So `Computer A` is shown twice because it visited at 09:10:00 and then visited again at 12:25:00 which means a difference of over 1 hour.

It's easy to 'GROUP BY Computer' but the other, I wouldn't know where to start. Any help on this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! 
Also: this is **NOT** an HTML site - no need to use tons of `<p>` and `<br />` tags - just use two or more cr/lf ....

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: What's the output if this **ComputerA   2012-04-28 12:25:00** is this instead **ComputerA   2012-04-28 09:11:00** ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this with a simple `GROUP BY`. This operator only works on single columns - e.g. you could group by computer name or something, but you cannot add additional logic like *difference in time must be greater than one hour* or anything like that to the grouping.

What you can do - provided you're on SQL Server **2005** or newer (you didn't mention the version in your question) would be to use CTE's (Common Table Expressions). Those provide a way to slice'n'dice your data.

Here, I'm doing several things - first I'm "partitioning" the data by `ComputerName` and order by `VisitDate` and using `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a sequential number for each partition. Then the second CTE determines the "first" entry for each computer - the one with row number = 1 - and the third finally determines the difference in the `VisitDate` for each entry, compared to the entry with row number = 1. From that third CTE, I finally select those entries that either have row number = 1 (the first for each "partition"), or anything that has a difference in minutes of 60 or more.

Here's the code:

```
;WITH Computers AS
(
    SELECT
        ComputerName, VisitDate,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ComputerName ORDER BY VisitDate)
    FROM    
        dbo.YourComputerTable
),
FirstComputers AS
(
    SELECT ComputerName, VisitDate
    FROM Computers
    WHERE RN = 1
),
SelectedComputers AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.ComputerName, c.VisitDate, c.RN,
        DiffToFirst = ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.VisitDate, fc.VisitDate))
    FROM Computers c
    INNER JOIN FirstComputers fc ON c.ComputerName = fc.ComputerName
)
SELECT * 
FROM SelectedComputers
WHERE RN = 1 OR DiffToFirst >= 60
```

Comment: @Siva `ABS` returns the `ABSolute value` of a number (without the sign).

Comment: @Siva: no, but depending on which order you have the two dates in, you might get +60 or -60 - thus I chose to use `ABS()` around it to not have to deal with those two possibilities.

Comment: This does not work when multiple dates are used. Try this: INSERT YourComputerTable (ComputerName,VisitDate) VALUES ('ComputerA','1/1/2012 09:00'); Now run the solution above.

Comment: @brian: you're right - there's a problem there. Not clear what the original intent was in this case - I based my solution on the data provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you've upgraded to SQL Server 2012, you can use LAG for this.

```
with Lagged as (
  select
    Computer,
    VisitDate,
    LAG(VisitDate,1) over (
      partition by Computer
      order by VisitDate
    ) as LastVisit
  from @Visit
)
  select
    Computer,
    VisitDate
  from Lagged
  where LastVisit is null
  or VisitDate > dateadd(hour,1,LastVisit);
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe9e0/2).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

CTEs to show all computers having at least one visit, or visits before and after gaps > 60 minutes.

```
create table compVisits (Computer varchar(20), VisitDate datetime)
go
insert into compVisits values
('ComputerA', '2012-04-28 09:00:00')
, ('ComputerA', '2012-04-28 09:05:00')
, ('ComputerA', '2012-04-28 09:10:00')
, ('ComputerB', '2012-04-28 09:30:00')
, ('ComputerB', '2012-04-28 09:32:00')
, ('ComputerB', '2012-04-28 09:44:00')
, ('ComputerB', '2012-04-28 09:56:00')
, ('ComputerB', '2012-04-28 10:25:00')
, ('ComputerA', '2012-04-28 12:25:00')
, ('ComputerC', '2012-04-28 12:30:00')
, ('ComputerC', '2012-04-28 12:35:00')
, ('ComputerC', '2012-04-28 12:45:00')
, ('ComputerC', '2012-04-28 12:55:00')

; WITH a as ( --Initial row count
    select *, r=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Computer ORDER BY VisitDate)
    FROM compVisits
)
, b as ( -- gaps >60 minutes
    SELECT a1.Computer, a1.VisitDate
    FROM a a1
    INNER JOIN a a2 ON a1.Computer=a2.Computer AND (a1.r+1)=a2.r
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE,a1.VisitDate,a2.VisitDate)>60
    UNION
    SELECT a2.Computer, a2.VisitDate
    FROM a a1
    INNER JOIN a a2 ON a1.Computer=a2.Computer AND (a1.r+1)=a2.r
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE,a1.VisitDate,a2.VisitDate)>60
)
-- at least one visit
SELECT a1.Computer, a1.VisitDate
FROM a a1
WHERE r=1
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE Computer=a1.Computer)

UNION

-- gaps >60 minutes
SELECT * FROM b
ORDER BY VisitDate
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I believe that the INNER JOIN will remove all computers where only 1 visit has been recorded.